# How to set my exit node from within tails by using the command line

Tags: configuration, tails

I would like to set exit node from within tails by using the command line. I am currently using tails live CD. I tried to do this by saving in torrc but it won't save. I though it might store in RAM, but it does not. I tried command line `ExitNodes{US}`. It gave out this `bash:ExitNodes{US}: command not found`. Can I do this. If so how? What do I type in terminal?

Comment: I have the same problem I want to change the exit node can you tell me how you did it.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way should be to put it into your `torrc`. You wrote in your question, that you couldn't save the file. Did you maybe edit it as the wrong user? Usually you need superuser rights (`sudo`).

If you want to pass the option on the command line, you could do the following:

```
tor --ExitNodes "{us}"
```

You need to put `{us}` insides quotes, because otherwise your shell will interpret it in a different way. Another way to realise it is to use backslashes:

```
tor --ExitNodes \{us\}
```

You can also use `echo` to write into your `torrc`:

```
echo ExitNodes "{us}" | sudo tee -a /etc/tor/torrc
```

This command appends the line `ExitNodes {us}` to your `torrc.`

Comment: I am getting this error form command line and can not connect to the net. As to the etc/tor/torrc file configuration it says read only and can not save it. May be this is because I am using live CD. Any thing I can do about command line? amnesia@amnesia:~$ tor --ExitNodes "{US}" Oct 08 04:00:49.203 [notice] Tor v0.2.6.9 (git-145b2587d1269af4) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.19-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1e and Zlib 1.2.7. Oct 08 04:00:49.203 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning Oct 08 04:00:49.203 [notice] Rea

Comment: Take a look at my answer above. Too long ot include in comments

Comment: Could you try the following command: 》echo ExitNodes "{us}" | sudo tee -a /etc/tor/torrc《? What happens?

Comment: Thanx it works with this echo command